# Facebook inventory estimator service

Tags: facebook, nosql

Facebook has a super cool service called "inventory estimator" that estimates the reach for an advertisement based on different filters (http://www.facebook.com/ads/create).

Does some one know which technologies involved in this service ? 
Any details about the implementation would be great.

Haggai

Comment: btw - the same question goes to Google analytics custom segmentation feature.